# using sed to change date format in a file from month day, year to day month year

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with the following:

```
$ cat file.txt
on that date April 02, 2020 end of line
March 5, 2021 helloooo world
J 14, 2022
error 3, bye
```

I want to change the date format from "month day, year" to "day month year". The month always starts with a capital letter, the day is one or two digits and the year is 4 digits.

Desired output:

```
on that date 02 April 2020 end of line
5 March 2021 helloooo world
14 J 2022
error 3, bye
```

i tried the below, can get the day and year but cannot get the month

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]*[0-9]), ([0-9]{4})//g'
```

How can I do this with sed on a Linux system?

Comment: `14 J 2022` is not a valid date; how you validate which is date which is not then? like `02 Ja 02` is a valid date and how?

Comment: as i mentioned here, The month always starts with a capital letter, the day is one or two digits and the year is 4 digits and always in this format month day, year

Comment: @peterlouis so would `Fooobarasdasdkjansdjiabskdjabsd 00 9999` be a valid date?

Comment: OK, so will not validate a string like `Xyz 99, 2020` is not a valid date and you will just change it to `99 Xyz 2020`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way assuming your data are as you show and you don't have anything like `Foo 12, 0000` which should not be considered as a date):

```
$ sed -E 's/([A-Z][a-z]+) ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})\b/\2 \1 \3/g' file
on that date 02 April 2020 end of line
5 March 2021 helloooo world
J 14, 2022
error 3, bye
```

We look for a capital letter followed by one or more lower case letters (`[A-Z][a-z]+`), then a space and one or two numbers (`[0-9]{1,2}`), then a comma and a space and exactly 4 numbers followed by a word-boundary (`\b`: a word to non-word transition; this will match a space, or the end of the line or anything else that isn't a word character). The parentheses *capture* the relevant groups into `\1`, `\2` and `\3` which we then use for the replacement.

Note that this does not work for `J 14, 2022` since that is not a valid date. For example, is `M 14 2020` the 14th of March or of May? If you really want to match things like that as well, you can try:

```
$ sed -E 's/([A-Z][a-z]*) ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})\b/\2 \1 \3/g' file
on that date 02 April 2020 end of line
5 March 2021 helloooo world
14 J 2022
error 3, bye
```

Finally, you could also make it a bit more specific by only looking for capital letters that can be found as the first letter of a month:

```
sed -E 's/([JFMASOND][a-z]*) ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})\b/\2 \1 \3/g' file
```

Comment: appreciated! thanks a lot. worked

Comment: FWIW you could make it even more specific by changing `[a-z]*` to `[a-z]{2,8}`.